# Bash script - Start two background processes, wait for both to complete and get their output in variables

Tags: bash, nonblocking

So, in my script, I want to start two processes in the background, after this I want to wait for both to complete and I want to get the stdout of the processes in variables.

To run in background, I can use
`command &`

To get the result in a variable I can run the command within backquotes.

But when I do `command &` within backquotes, the whole thing becomes blocking.

So, how do I solve my problem?

Answer (score 4):

Commands run in background run in a child process, and there is no way for a child process to modify a parameter (variable) in the parent process. So technically, what you're looking for is impossible.

However, you can store the child's `stdout` (and, if you wish, `stderr`) in a file; you'll just have to make sure to give the file a unique name. (See `man mktemp`, for example.) After you `wait` for the background process to finish, you can read the temporary file into a parameter, and delete the file.

```
tmp1=$(mktemp)
tmp2=$(mktemp)
command1 > "$tmp1" &
command2 > "$tmp2" &
wait
OUTPUT1=$( < "$tmp1" ) && rm "$tmp1"
OUTPUT2=$( < "$tmp2" ) && rm "$tmp2"
```